# Counting number of odd permutations using determinants.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

$\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}$$\def\b{\mathbf}$
Determine using definition of determinants why half of total permutations of $(1, ... ,9)$ are odd ?

Let $A$ be a $9 \times 9$ invertible  matrix, then $$\det A = \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Perm(9)}} A_{\sigma(1), 1}...A_{\sigma(9), 9}\sign(\sigma)$$

If I understand the problem then I just need to count the number of times $\sign(\sigma)$ is negative.

Since switching odd number of columns(rows) in a determinant makes it's sign negative. So I need to determine the total number of odd switches in $\det A = D(\b v_1, ..., \b v_9)$. I think this can be done by counting number of 1 column, 3 column, 5 column, 7 column and 9 column switches. Although I haven't calculated number of odd switches, my proposed method looks tedious and diverts from the intent of the author.

How to solve this question by using only definition and properties of determinants ?

Comment: The determinant of the all-one matrix is zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How's that relevant here ?

Comment: Can you write the determinant of the all-one matrix as the number of odd permutations plus the number of even permutations?

Comment: @ml0105 If $A$ is all one matrix then $$0 = \det A = \sum_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Perm(9)}}\sign(\sigma)$$ since $\sign(\sigma) = \pm 1$ and total number of permutations is even, therefore the number of $-1$ and $1$ are equal. Hence half of all permutations are odd. Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes.$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: That was easy, just needed a small hint.

Comment: The standard algebraic proof is to establish an explicit bijection between even and odd permutations of $Sym(n)$. This proof just shows the existence of such a bijection. It’s worthwhile to make note of this idea.

Comment: @ml0105 For the given question only proving the existence of a bijection is enough right ?

Comment: Yes- this is just an existence proof. I just wanted to point out the underlying idea. :-)